# Trying to implement a vector passed by reference for use with a Binary Tree, what am I missing?

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write code to offload the inorder contents of a Binary Tree into a vector.
IE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BinaryTree tree;
    vector <double> v;

    // Test iterative insert
    cout << "Inserting the numbers 5 8 3 12 9.";
    tree.insert(5);
    tree.insert(8);
    tree.insert(3);
    tree.insert(12);
    tree.insert(9);


    // Test vectorExport()
    tree.vectorExport(v);
}
```

I am getting a whole bunch of errors because I don't think I'm implementing it correctly in the member function. I don't know if I'm using the & symbol in the wrong spot or its not in a place it should be. Anyones help would be appreciated. 

 This is the error I am getting:
`[Error] prototype for 'void BinaryTree::vectorExport(BinaryTree::TreeNode*, std::vector<double>&)' does not match any in class 'BinaryTree'`

**Here is my class:**

```
#ifndef DOUBLEBINARYTREE_H
#define DOUBLEBINARYTREE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class BinaryTree
{
private:
   // The TreeNode class is used to build the tree.
    class TreeNode
    {
       friend class BinaryTree;
       double value;
       TreeNode *left;
       TreeNode *right;
       TreeNode(double value1, TreeNode *left1 = NULL,
                            TreeNode *right1 = NULL)
       {
          value = value1;
          left = left1;
          right = right1;
       }          
    };
    TreeNode *root;     // Pointer to the root of the tree

    // Various helper member functions.
    void insert(TreeNode *&, double);
    bool search(TreeNode *, double);
    void destroySubtree(TreeNode *);
    void remove(TreeNode *&, double);
    void makeDeletion(TreeNode *&);
    void vectorExport(TreeNode *, vector<double>);

public:
   // These member functions are the public interface.
    BinaryTree()        // Constructor
        { root = NULL; }
    ~BinaryTree()       // Destructor
        { destroySubtree(root); }
    void insert(double num)
        { insert(root, num); }
    bool search(double num)
        { search(root, num); }
    void remove(double num)
        { remove(root, num);}
    void vectorExport(vector<double> & v)
        { vectorExport(root, v); }

};
```

**Here is the actual function:**

```
//*********************************************************
// This function offloads tree contents to a vector       *
//*********************************************************
void BinaryTree::vectorExport(TreeNode *tree, vector<double> &v)
{
    if (tree)
    {
       vectorExport(tree->left, vector<double> v);
       v.push_back(tree->value);
       vectorExport(tree->right, vector <double> v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the argument as being passed by reference, e.g.

```
void vectorExport(TreeNode *, vector<double>&);
```

not

```
void vectorExport(TreeNode *, vector<double>);
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I missed something